# How can i use RestKit to get stream of data (NSData)

Tags: restkit, nsdata

I have a rest server that receives a json but returns content of a file. 
I am looking for a way to get the content of the file as NSData.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RestKit only to create the `NSURLRequest` that you're going to send, then deal with actually sending it and handling the response data yourself, probably using `AFNetworking` (which RestKit is currently built on top of so you have direct access to).